# void is an invalid type

Tags: java, android

why this is  showing error and how to resolve it ? it is saying that sendMessage can't be void...

```
          public void sendMessage(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: Why two close brackets for this method

Comment: You're inside a class extending Activity, right? As in here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture02/lecture02.html

Comment: Post the code that's calling this method please.

Comment: yes.. public class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: we need more code, if possible put here  the code for the whole file/class

Comment: Yeah, I think Ridcully may have nailed it in his/her answer (oh, who oh why doesn't English have a gender-neutral personal possessive singular pronoun?). To be certain, post your entire MainActivty class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lay before this method declaration. The java compiler believes you are declaring a variable `sendMessage`here and assumes you want `void` to be its type.
Probably there's a bracket missing in the code above the method.